# Iterating within a function using for loop doesn't work?

Tags: python

When I use for loop within a function (see below), the block of statements below the for loop is not iterated,

```
def F(rho, m, E, v_rho, v_m, v_E):
    for n in xrange(N):
        #Update conserved quantities
        rho = G(Evolve_rho1(rho))
        m = momentum(Evolve_m1(m))
        E = Energy(Evolve_E1(E))
        v_rho = rho_v(Evolve_rho_v(rho))
        v_m = m_v(Evolve_mv(m))
        v_E = E_v(Evolve_Ev(E))

    return (rho, m, E, v_rho, v_m, v_E)
```

since after calling the function in this way: `density, momentum, Energy, dflux, mflux, Eflux = F(rho, m, E, v_rho, v_m, v_E)`, and 
print for example density, leads to wrong answer.

But if I only use for loop like below, it works fine.

```
for n in xrange(N):
    #Update conserved quantities
    rho = G(Evolve_rho1(rho))
    m = momentum(Evolve_m1(m))
    E = Energy(Evolve_E1(E))
    v_rho = rho_v(Evolve_rho_v(rho))
    v_m = m_v(Evolve_mv(m))
    v_E = E_v(Evolve_Ev(E))
print rho
print m
```

etc., give correct results.

Any suggestion is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: This might be a pasting error, but in the function N is not defined.

Comment: @Chris Pickett not having N defined would throw an Exception ...though it would be good to know that it wasn't set to 0

Comment: Exactly, not knowing N, it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's not the for- loop.

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you solve your problem.  Please devise a minimal example that demonstrates the problem and post the whole module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your missing the difference between a global and a local vlue for `N`.  As you've written it, the value of `N` in the `F` *function* will be whatever N is when `F` is called, not when it's defined.  So if at the time `F` is called `N==0`, then the loop block will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The function was using global variables instead of local which were updated in each iteration in F(). The solution is to pass variables as parameters and define `

```
def F(rho, m, E, v_rho, v_m, v_E):
    for n in xrange(N):                                  
        rho = G(Evolve_rho1(rho,v_rho,m))
        m  = momentum(Evolve_m1(rho,v_rho, m,v_m,E))
        E = Energy(Evolve_E1(rho, m, E, v_E))
        v_rho = rho_v(Evolve_rho_v(rho,v_rho,m))
        v_m =   m_v( Evolve_mv(rho,v_rho, m,v_m,E)) 
        v_E  =  E_v(Evolve_Ev(rho, m, E, v_E))
    return (rho, m, E, v_rho, v_m, v_E)
```

Thanks Folks for all your contributions.